# Submenu don't displayed with transform skewX option

Tags: wordpress, css, drop-down-menu

I first time used skewX transform option for my menu and now i have a problem.
http://diagoris.webhack.in.ua
Here is my menu structure. 
[image]

```
<ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu collapse navbar-collapse"><li id="menu-item-39" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-39"><a href="http://diagoris.webhack.in.ua/qui-sommes-nous/">Qui sommes nous</a>
<ul class="sub-menu" style="width: 1170px;">
<li id="menu-item-41" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-41"><a href="#">Qui sommes nous</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-40" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-40"><a href="#">Qui sommes nous</a></li>
```

Qui sommes nous
Qui sommes nous
[Q&A](http://diagoris.webhack.in.ua/qa/)
     [Events](http://diagoris.webhack.in.ua/events/)[Nous contacter](http://diagoris.webhack.in.ua/contact-us/)

When i hover on menu-item-39 submenu don't appear, i tried z-index, now, i have no idea how to fix it...
Help me, please...

Comment: change the z-index of #menu-main-menu and it will show up. I set it to 99 and it worked

Comment: @Berdesdan it works, great! Thank you so much :)